# Correlation of columns of two arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, correlation

I have two arrays: 900x421 and 900x147. I need to correlate all columns from these arrays so that the output is 421x147. In Matlab function `corr()` does it, but I can't find a function that does the same in python.

Comment: did you see: [numpy.corrcoef](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) ?

Comment: yes, but it gives an error: `all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 421 and the array at index 1 has size 147`

Comment: Transpose the inputs

Comment: it gives the same error

Comment: if both inputs are transposed I get as a result one array of shape `568`, but I need an array of `421x147`

Comment: Please provide the code of you failed attempts in your question

Answer (score 1):

the `numpy.corrcoef` function is the way to go. You need both arguments `x` and `y` to be of the same shape. You can do so by concatenate the two arrays. Let's say `arr1` is of shape 900x421 and `arr2` is of shape 900x147. You can do the following

```
import numpy as np
two_arrays = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=1) # 900x568
corr = np.corrcoef(two_arrays.T) # 568x568 array
desired_output = corr[0:421, 421:]
```

The `np.corrcoef` treats each row as a variable and each column as observation. That is why we need to transpose the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't work. resulting `corr` is 900x900, and `desired_output` is an empty array of shape 900x0. Also since my resulting arrays will be of different size hard coding the size doesn't really work for me. I'm trying to come up with a solution with loops over each column, but it seems suboptimal

Comment: You are right. I edited my code to fix that and I tested it. For the changing sizes of arrays, you can just replace the numeric values by something like `arr1.shape[1]` for example to get the 421 value.

Comment: But why should I select first 421 values and not last 421, or 421 from the middle? That seems pretty arbitrary, but I needspecifically 421 columns from one array correlated with another 147 values of another array

Comment: because I concatenated the second array `arr2` to the first array `arr1`. Numpy adds arrays in the same order you pass them to `np.concatenate`. So the first 421 columns in `two_arrays` correspond to the columns of `arr1`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! :)